# virtual machine to another computer?

Tags: vmware-server, vmware-player

I am using windows xp as a virtual machine installed on windows 7.
My laptop(computer A) is connected to another computer(B) through a LAN cable. What configuration should I make (what settings should I put on VMware, default gateway...) in order to successfully ping from machine B to the XP virtual machine on laptop A.

In other words I want to connect my virtual machine to another computer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply configure the network adapter on VMWare to bind on your physical network adapter.

Comment: Yup, I'm not sure about VMWare, but in Virtual Box this is called "Bridge Mode"

Comment: its the same in vmware.